# modify captured pcap and write back

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I need to read captured pcap file, that contains some proprietary descriptor appended by FPGA at the start of file right after MAC header, add extra 2 bytes to the descriptor and write back.

I'm trying to implement this in C using libpcap library on linux. Am I right that I will need to call pcap_dump_open() and pcap_dump() to write buffer? Also, is is true that I'll need to increment caplen and and 'len' from pcap_pkthdr accordingly (add 2) prior writing the buffer with pcap_dump?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to read captured pcap file, that contains some proprietary descriptor appended by FPGA at the start of file right after MAC header

So the packet format is, in order:

- MAC header
- proprietary descriptor
- payload

?

> add extra 2 bytes to the descriptor and write back.

So the proprietary descriptor will become 2 bytes longer, moving the payload down by two bytes?

> I'm trying to implement this in C using libpcap library on linux. Am I right that I will need to call pcap_dump_open() and pcap_dump() to write buffer?

That's probably the easiest way to do it.

> Also, is is true that I'll need to increment caplen and and 'len' from pcap_pkthdr accordingly (add 2) prior writing the buffer with pcap_dump?

If you're adding 2 bytes to the packet, yes, you'll need to increment both the `caplen` and `len` fields of the `pcap_pkthdr` structure by 2 before writing the packet out.

Unless you know for certain that `caplen` is large enough to include the MAC header and all the data in the proprietary descriptor up to the point where you'll be adding the 2 bytes in question, you should also check to make sure that it is and, if it isn't, don't modify the packet in question and only modify `len`, not `caplen`, for that particular packet.